# How can I start the service only if there are incoming connections?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, service

Microsoft offers the following sample for writing a service in Windows:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/svc-cpp

This sample contains a call to the [`CreateService()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-createservicea) function with the following limited set of `hwStartType` values:

- `SERVICE_AUTO_START` (start during system startup);
- `SERVICE_BOOT_START` (for drivers);
- `SERVICE_DEMAND_START` (start by service control manager on-demand);
- `SERVICE_DISABLED` (service cannot be started);
- `SERVICE_SYSTEM_START` (for drivers);

I would like to write a service that is activated only when a TCP connection request appears on a specific port.

Ideally, I would like the program not even to be in RAM (the Service Manager would listen to the specified port) until a connection request appears, and then the necessary descriptor would be issued to the program by the Service Manager.

There is a similar elegant solution when using systems with systemd initialization subsystem ([socket-activation](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html)).

Is it possible to implement something like this within Windows? If not, which alternative solution is most suitable for this task?

This problem can be "solved" (in fact, just ignored). You can start the service by selecting one of the options listed above (`hwStartType`). Or, you can additionally write another miniature service that only listens to a given port, and then transfers control to a "large" service.

Such "solutions", although acceptable, are not elegant: why should the program hang in memory all the time when no action is taking place (and in my case, it really is: connections to the server are quite rare)?

Comment: inetd has been around almost as long as TCP/IP

Comment: There is no inetd on Windows. inetd (xinetd) is available by default only on UNIX-like systems. Am I wrong?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/305960/appropriate-substitute-for-inetd-on-windows-platform

Comment: What is this "hang in memory" you refer to? If a program is doing nothing, it will just be paged out. What problem are you trying to solve here? You just need a single service.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. The guys from MSDN gave the answer:
Windows services can be configured to start when certain trigger events occur. More details can be found at the following links:

- [Service Trigger Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-trigger-events);
- [SERVICE_TRIGGER Structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_trigger);

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I don't see how this helps you.  There is no pre-defined trigger event for when a TCP connection is pending, as you asked for. In fact, a TCP connection can't even become pending unless an application/service is actively running a socket that is bound and listening on the desired port to begin with. The only 2 defined triggers for network activity are when a port is opened/closed on the Windows firewall, and network packets are received on a given network interface. Neither of those really solve your issue.